# Could I use this informal explanation for Hawking radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, cosmology

I need to explain Hawking radiation to my classmates for a homework. Could I use this informal explanation? (unfortunately without math). Correct me if I need to change/add something:

Quantum fluctuations on vacuum generates pairs of entangled virtual particles that “exists” only for a brief moment of time and then annihilate each other, turning into nothing, without violating any law. But when this pair is created NEAR (out) the event horizon of a black hole which has enormous gravitational force, those virtual particles are “splitted” apart and actually become “real” particles with real mass and energy, and one of them goes inside the black hole while the other one has gained sufficient energy to leave the attraction and escape. As the “real” particles pair separation was produced by the black hole's gravitational energy, and only “half” of the energy used was “recovered”, the escape of one of the particles lowers the total mass of the black hole, causing them to “evaporate” on a long period of time.

Comment: It is OK ,  it is "split" not "spitted" . You could refer to the heisenberg uncertainty in time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation

Comment: @anna v. Not really related to the Q. Where I can find something serious but not mathematical about this popping out of particle-antiparticle couples or even of just particle popping out due to quantum fluctuations (if possible)? I suspect that out of a frame (perhaps they are virtual) it is just a picture with no much meaning as for one, perhaps, can expect multiple big bangs happening at whatever time and the likes.

Comment: @Alchimista  single particles cannot pop up without violating quantum numbers and energy momentum conservation. I do not know of a reference with no mathematics. The whole of quantum mechanics is built on mathematics.

Comment: Ok but are you really thinking of particles popping out and disappearing around us?

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes. English is not my primary language. This is just a summary, I'll explain everything more detailed on a cardboard, in steps, a little of the concepts of QFT, uncertainty principle on time and energy and on momentum and position, then how black holes “work”... etc.

Comment: @Alchimista Those are virtual particles, not really particles at all. They pop in existence and then annihilate. “The most interesting way I've heard it explained is that the pair needs to annihilate “before the universe realizes that its law has been broken.“ ” It can be described as “off shell” particles, not really full complete particles.

Comment: The time that they exist before annihilating is so small. It is described by Δt < ħ/ΔE.